# Wordpress login security

Tags: login, security

I have put up a logging script on my wp-login page. I noticed that a particular ip address- 193.176.147.7 has been consistently visiting my login page for some days now. The vitis are always in quick succession and 3 times exacly. That is the no. Of failed attempts my plugin allows, before suspending an ip. Should I be concerned and is there any precaution that I can take? For example blocking that particular IP will help or should I block some range of IPs? I did a whatismyip.com lookup, but they had no information. Does changing the name of my wp-login.php to something else helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the requests will still happen, even if it results in a 404. If you keep logging, you'll also notice attempts to log in to Drupal, Joomla, and other major CMS, including server exploits for IIS Apache and Nginx

This is because they're automated opportunistic requests, they're not actually looking at your site, they're only looking for successful logins. Most sites get these, sometimes in large spikes, sometimes as consistent background noise.

If you're worried about your security though, I'd suggest that you:

- Add a brute force login mechanism, such as the one included in Jetpack, or the popular limit logins plugin
- Force a minimum password strength, there are several plugins that can do this for you, though I cant recommend one
- Use 2 factor authentication

Other than that, there isn't anything you can do to eliminate the possibility short of a major breakthrough in computer security research. Moving your login page will either break things, or it'll only work for those bots that are particularly stupid.

Anyone can visit the login page of a site via rewrite rules by going to `/login` if pretty permalinks are turned on, they can use XMLRPC, and they can visit the admin area at `wp-admin` and be redirected to the login page. If you move the admin area, aside from breaking things, the user can still visit `/admin` and be redirected anyway. Moving things sounds like the answer, but it really isn't, it'll just give you a sense of false security, which is far more dangerous.

Comment: As an added layer of security for the paranoid you can password protect `wp-admin/` directory (being sure to exclude the `admin-ajax.php` used by some front-facing plug-ins.). While this won't protect `wp-login.php` (though you could do that too). This adds a layer which is completely independent of WordPress.

Comment: `Use 2 factor authentication` is there native 2FA for wordpress?

Comment: there's an official plugin for it as well as multiple 3rd party solutions, as well as using SSO

Answer (score 0):

A [Google search](https://www.google.gr/search?q=193.176.147.7) for the IP showed, this IP is known as a spammer IP. A quick check on [MXtoolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3A193.176.147.7&run=toolpage) shows, it is blacklisted by blocklist.de, CBL and Spamhouse ZEN. I would suggest to ban the IP.

Some interesting suggestions, how to prevent wp-login.php from a brute force attack can be found on [MNX Solutions](http://www.mnxsolutions.com/apache/blocking-wordpress-brute-force-attacks-against-wp-login-php.html).